# use cmake compile a C++ project to Webassembly, emcc report a error in iostream header

Tags: android, c++, webassembly, emscripten, parcel

I'm trying to compile the Android Native Parcel to webassembly, when i use the emscripten, an error in  was report. but i write a cout<<"helloworld"; program the iostream work fun. i don't know what's wrong here.
here is the compile log

```
 username@rjyby04  ~/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/build   develop ±  emmake make      
make: make
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libskytvclient.dir/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/api/TVPlayer.cpp.o
In file included from /work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/api/TVPlayer.cpp:14:
In file included from /work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/./TvClient.h:4:
In file included from /work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../3rd/androidtool/include/binder/Parcel.h:32:
In file included from /work2/username/software/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/iostream:44:
In file included from /work2/username/software/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/istream:165:
In file included from /work2/username/software/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/ostream:172:
/work2/username/software/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/locale:761:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'strtoll_l'
  761 |         long long __ll = strtoll_l(__a, &__p2, __base, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);
      |                          ^
/work2/username/software/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/c++/v1/locale:801:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'strtoull_l'
  801 |         unsigned long long __ll = strtoull_l(__a, &__p2, __base, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);
      |                                   ^
2 errors generated.
em++: error: '/work2/username/software/emsdk/upstream/bin/clang++ -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -fignore-exceptions -fvisibility=default -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false 
-mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr -D__EMSCRIPTEN_SHARED_MEMORY__=1 
-DEMSCRIPTEN --sysroot=/work2/username/software/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include/fakesdl -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include/compat 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../component/skytv/client/webassembly/FakeHeader 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../3rd/androidtool/include 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../general/skos_cpp/inc 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../general/database/stationtable/src 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../component/skytvbase/include 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../component/skytv/client/webassembly/3rd
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../component/skytv/include/api 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/../../../../general/include 
-I/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/webassembly/. 
-std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/libskytvclient.dir/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/api/TVPlayer.cpp.o 
-MF CMakeFiles/libskytvclient.dir/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/api/TVPlayer.cpp.o.d 
-c -pthread /work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/api/TVPlayer.cpp 
-o CMakeFiles/libskytvclient.dir/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/api/TVPlayer.cpp.o' failed (returned 1)

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libskytvclient.dir/work2/username/develop/Eurasia/Eurasia4.2.0/component/skytv/client/api/TVPlayer.cpp.o] 错误 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libskytvclient.dir/all] 错误 2
make: *** [all] 错误 2
emmake: error: 'make' failed (returned 2)
```

I have tried compile a simple cout<<"helloworld" ,this worked